# Algebraic dependence of $(a^a,b^b)$ or $(a^b,b^a)$ for algebraic $a,b$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $a,b$ be algebraic numbers.

Assume $(a^a,b^b)$ or $(a^b,b^a)$ are algebraically dependent.

> Is it true that $\frac{\log{a}}{\log{b}}$ is rational?

Schnauel's conjecture implies $(\log{a},\log{b},a\log{a},b\log{b})$
or $(\log{a},\log{b},a\log{b},b\log{a})$ are linearly dependent.

**EDIT** Gerry Myerson solved the original question. Let in addition
require $a,b$ to be irrational.

Comment: [This question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/255481/30186) (and the answer) is relevant - it gives a positive answer for the case $a^a,b^b$ under Schanuel's conjecture.

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE:** somehow, I've missed the assumption that $a,b$ are supposed to be algebraic. The following is a counterexample without this assumption.

Consider $a=\log_2 3,b=2\log_2 3$. Then $b^b=2^{2\log_2 3}(\log_2 3)^{2\log_2 3}=9(a^a)^2$. However,
$$\frac{\log b}{\log a}=\frac{\log_2 b}{\log_2 a}=\frac{\log_22+\log_2a}{\log_2a}=1+\frac{1}{\log_2\log_2 3}.$$
If this was rational, then $2^{\log_2\log_2 3}=\log_2 3$ would be an algebraic irrational and, by Gelfond-Schneider, $2^{\log_2 3}=3$ would be transcendental.

**EDIT:** I believe the answer is *yes*, conditionally on Schanuel's conjecture. The approach is basically taken from [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/255488/30186), just slightly simplified.

Suppose $\frac{\log a}{\log b}$ is irrational. By Gelfond-Schneider, it must then be transcendental (else $a=b^{\log a/\log b}$ would be transcendental). I then claim $\log a,\log b,a\log a,b\log b$ are transcendental, as are $\log a,\log b,a\log a,b\log b$. If $r_1\log a+r_2\log b+r_3a\log a+r_4b\log b=0$ or $r_1\log a+r_2\log b+r_3b\log a+r_4a\log b=0$ was a nontrivial relation, then $\frac{\log a}{\log b}$ is either $-\frac{r_2+r_4b}{r_1+r_3a}$ or $-\frac{r_2+r_4a}{r_1+r_3b}$ (it follows quickly from irrationality of $a,b$ that the denominator cannot be zero in either case), which is necessarily an algebraic number, contradicting what was said above. This established linear independence.

Schanuel's conjecture gives that
$$\mathbb Q(\log a,\log b,a\log a,b\log b,a,b,a^a,b^b),\\
\mathbb Q(\log a,\log b,b\log a,a\log b,a,b,a^b,b^a)$$
have transcendence degree at least $4$, which implies (given algebraic relations between these numbers) that $a^a,b^b$ and $a^b,b^a$ must be algebraically independent pairs. If, moreover, $1,a,b$ are linearly independent, nearly the same argument shows that all four of $a^a,a^b,b^a,b^b$ are algebraically independent if $\frac{\log a}{\log b}$ is irrational.

Comment: Thank you. But $\log_2 3$ is not algebraic as wanted.

Comment: Oh, I'm extremely sorry. Somehow I have completely missed the assumption that they are supposed to be algebraic. Feel free to un-accept my answer.

Comment: @joro I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=1/3$, $b=2/3$. Then $b^b=2^{2/3}(a^a)^2$, so $(b^b)^3=4(a^a)^6$, and $a^a$ and $b^b$ are algebraically dependent. But if $\log a/\log b=p/q$, then $(1/3)^q=(2/3)^p$, contradicting unique factorization.